# Before insert trigger for a sequence

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, insert, sequence

I have to make a trigger that fills the primary key field user_id from a sequence.

So I did this first:

```
Create sequence user_seq;
```

Then I created the trigger. I also had to make the function that checks to see if the values in emp_id for the table users in the schema system_users exists in the table employees for the schema HRM_REPO. This part is in comments because it caused major issues.

```
create or replace trigger user_trig_bi
    Before insert on system_users.users
    for each row    
begin
            select user_seq.nextval
            into new.user_ID
            From dual;
      /*where exists (SELECT emp_id 
                    from hrm_repo.employees 
                    where hrm_repo.employees.emp_id = system_users.users.emp_id);*/
END;
```

I get the error that new.user_id must be defined.
If I do run the  where exists part, I get the notification that system_users.users.emp_id is an invalid identifier.

Please help me!

Regards,

Vinny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `new` with `:new`:

```
create or replace trigger user_trig_bi
    Before insert on system_users.users
    for each row    
begin
  select user_seq.nextval
  into :new.user_ID
  From dual;
END;
```

or simply:

```
create or replace trigger user_trig_bi
    Before insert on system_users.users
    for each row    
begin
  :new.user_ID := user_seq.nextval;
END;
```

Comment: Wow. I knew about the colon, yet fsr I missed it every time scrutinizing my code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry got the answer already. As an addition: you should never try to check referential integrity using triggers, it will not work correctly. You should add foreign key (system_users.users.emp_id) references hrm_repo.employees(emp_id) instead. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c22integ.htm if you missed it before.